# How do I recover my Facebook page without being able to access the email associated with the page

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, account-recovery

I have been a victim of Facebook page hacking and I don’t know how to get my page back. Please help me get my page back
I don’t know how to get in the email and I don’t have the phone numbers

Answer (score 0):

If you suspect your account was hacked, you can get immediate help by reporting the account here: [Report compromised account](https://www.facebook.com/hacked).

For more information check the Facebook Help Center -> [Hacked Accounts](https://www.facebook.com/help/131719720300233?ref=u2u)